# OpenCV VideoCapture() doesn't work - Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson-nano

OpenCV 4.5  -  Ubuntu  -  Jetson Nano 2GB

Hello I have a problem with getting video from my webcam (connected by USB to JetsonNano) by OpenCV

Here's my code:

```
 // cv::VideoCapture cap( ... );
    cv::Mat frame;
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::namedWindow("test", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            cap >> frame;
            cv::imshow("test", frame);
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
```

1 | `cv::VideoCapture cap(0)` gives me:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
```

2 | `cv::VideoCapture cap("/dev/video0")` gives me:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1761) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
Cannot open the video cam
```

3 | When I try to open camera by command, only this one work:
`$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=\"/dev/video0\" ! xvimagesink`
I gave it a try:
`cv::VideoCapture cap("v4l2src device=\"/dev/video0\" ! xvimagesink")` it gives me:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (803) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
Cannot open the video cam
```

If I gave other sinks : autosink or appsink, it's also doesn't work.

4 | I tried the solution from that link
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/sony-camera-module-cannot-be-opened-with-opencv-on-xavier/84003

`cv::VideoCapture cap("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=UYVY,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink")` and it's gives me :

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1761) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ERROR:0] global /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (142) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.0) /home/legion/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=UYVY,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

**Someone knows what's going on and how to fix it?**

Edit#1:
My OpenCV buildinfo :

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown
  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/legion/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown
  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-11-24T13:09:24Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.9.140-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.10.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE
  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    NEON FP16
      required:                  NEON
      disabled:                  VFPV3
  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.5.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fopenmp -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:
  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency sfm shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv java js julia matlab ovis viz
    Applications:                perf_tests examples apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES
  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.30)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.56.4)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO
  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
      avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
      avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
      swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
      avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.2 interface 11102)
  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             53
    NVIDIA PTX archs:
  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.0.0)
  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/legion/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load
  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.17)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.17)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
    install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.9)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
    numpy:                       /home/legion/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.4)
    install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO
  Install to:                    /usr
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks ~~

Comment: Its looks like OS does not recognize the CAM. Open the OS console and type ls -ltrh /dev/video* or  v4l2-ctl --list-devices

Comment: @JuliánOviedo, OS recognize cam, it's appear on device list, and when I use ```$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=\"/dev/video0\" ! xvimagesink``` I normally have a vision from my camera

Comment: Do you have OpenCV built with both `ffmpeg` and `gstreamer`?

Comment: @mibrahimy I added my OpenCV buildInfo, it seems I have it build with both of thease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For points 1 and 2, you can test by passing the second argument to `VideoCapture(filename[, apiPreference])`. Since you have OpenCV built with `ffmpeg` and `v4l2`. I would try the following options  `cv::CAP_FFMPEG`, and `CAP_V4L2`. For point 4, make sure your webcam is 1080p.

Comment: CAP_V4L2 Solved my issue! Thanks